# I can't seem to get the program to output the highest number inputted it just outputs done instead

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that repeatedly asks a user for a positive number until no number is entered. The program should then output the highest number, the total and the average of the numbers entered.

I can't seem to get it to work and it just outputs done as the highest number inputted.

The code:

```
import math
def adder():
    num=input("enter positive number")
    total=0
    count=0
    num1=0
    while num.isnumeric():
        num = int(num)
        total = total+num
        num = input("enter positive number if finished enter done")
        num1=num
        count=count+1
    if num>num1:
        num1=num
    if num == "done":
        print("the total of the numbers is {}".format(total))
        print("the average of the numbers is {}".format(total/count)
        print("the highest number inputted was {}".format(num1))
```

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Post the full code, and the full input/output, as plain text.

Comment: Please read ; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please think carefully about the logic of the code. If `num1` should end up as the highest value, then how many times should the `if num>num1:` code run? Only once, or repeatedly for each number that is input? Therefore, should it be inside the loop, or outside? Is it?

Comment: thank you very much his was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution. I tried to keep to your initial structure so you could see what you could do to fix it.

```py
def adder():
    num=int(input("enter positive number"))
    total=0
    count=0
    max_num=0
    while isinstance(num, int):
        count += 1
        total = total+num
        try:
            num = input("enter positive number if finished enter done")
            num = int(num)
        except ValueError: #this will run once the number can't be converted into an integer
            break
        if num>max_num:
            max_num=num
    if num == "done":
        print("the total of the numbers is {}".format(total))
        print("the average of the numbers is {}".format(total/count))
        print("the highest number inputted was {}".format(max_num))
```

Answer (score -2):

Your original code is:

```
import math
def adder():
    num=input("enter positive number")
    total=0
    count=0
    num1=0
    while num.isnumeric():
        num = int(num)
        total = total+num
        num = input("enter positive number if finished enter done")
        num1=num
        count=count+1
    if num>num1:
        num1=num
    if num == "done":
        print("the total of the numbers is {}".format(total))
        print("the average of the numbers is {}".format(total/count)
        print("the highest number inputted was {}".format(num1))
```

There are a few problems with this.

1. math is imported, but not used
2. num1 is highest number, but you wrote num1=num in the loop
3. the if statement is outside the while loop
4. this way of doing it is much longer and less concise than putting every number in a list first.
5. the num = input(...) would make num be a string, not int

My code:

```
def adder():
    num_list = []
    num = input("enter positive number: ")
    while num.isnumeric():
        num_list.append(int(num))
        num = input("enter positive number if finished enter done: ")
    if num == "done":
        total = sum(num_list)
        print("the sum of the numbers is {}".format(total))
        print("the average of the numbers is {}".format(total/len(num_list)))
        print("the highest number inputted was {}".format(max(num_list)))
adder()
```

Comment: *"this way of doing it is much longer and less concise than putting every number in a list first."* But it's much more memory-efficient. It doesn't really matter for a small learning exercise like this, but for example if you were consuming numbers from a huge file and all you cared about was the sum, average and maximum, you would indeed want to iterate one number at a time and discard it, rather than bringing the whole lot into memory.

Comment: thank you very much